# GoLang and opening MS SQL Compact files (.sdf)

Tags: go, sql-server-ce

As the title suggests, I'm attempting to open an SDF/MSSQL CE database in GoLang.  Is this possible?

The GoLang Libraries I've found do not appear to suppot MSSQL CE database connections.

I hope this is not a duplicate, but I can not find info online

Comment: https://godoc.org/?q=MSSQL or http://go-search.org/search?q=MSSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it would hardly be possible to work with these files directly as they merely are on-disk storage format, and note that MSSQL DBs of all flavors use `.sdf` as the extension of the file names of their DBs, so by itself they mean nothing.

OTOH, one direct way to approach this problem would be using
[OLE DB layer](https://github.com/mattn/go-adodb).

Answer (score -1):

You can also try to use

https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb

to connect to MSSQL Express instance like that:

```
sqlserver://sa@localhost/SQLExpress?database=master&connection+timeout=30
```

Comment: The question is about SQL Server Compact, not SQL Server